# Dismissing keyboard from textfield inside tableviewcell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, keyboard, uitextfield

I have a custom tableViewCell which has a textfield inside.

How to dismiss keyboard when tap any place outside the textfields?

Do I have to look through all cells use `[cell.textView resignFirstResponder]`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code :

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
  [self.view endEditing:YES];
}
```

Or you can add a tap gesture recognizer :

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *tapper;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    tapper = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]
                initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleSingleTap:)];
    tapper.cancelsTouchesInView = NO;
    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:tapper];
}

- (void)handleSingleTap:(UITapGestureRecognizer *) sender
{
    [self.view endEditing:YES];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No, you can just use:

```
[self.view endEditing:YES];
```

> endEditing:
>
> Causes the view (or one of its embedded text fields) to resign the first responder status.
>
> Parameters: force
>
> Specify YES to force the first responder to resign,
>   regardless of whether it wants to do so.